# SoapHttpClientProtocol log response xml

Tags: c#, web-services, webservice-client, soaphttpclientprotocol

For a couple of days we have problem with our app. We use SoapHttpClientProtocol in order to invoke java mbeans. This basically makes a call to a java webservice to invoke methods.

Our problem is that sometimes we get the following exception:

> There is an error in XML document (1, 172089).    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   DynamicMBeanResourceBinding.Invoke(OperationRequestType
>   ManagedResourceOperation) in JMXConnectorService.cs:line 781    at
>   JMXWSClient.InvokeMethodOnObject(String objectName, String methodName,
>   ParameterType[] paramValue) in connectivity\Client.cs:line 132
>
> Caused by: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements
>   are not closed: Icon

Our last code in the communication layer is:

```
 /// <remarks/>
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("soapHeaders", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://jsr262.dev.java.net/DynamicMBeanResource/Invoke", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ManagedResourceOperationResult", Namespace = "http://jsr262.dev.java.net/jmxconnector")]
public GenericValueType Invoke([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://jsr262.dev.java.net/jmxconnector")] OperationRequestType ManagedResourceOperation)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Invoke", new object[] {ManagedResourceOperation});
    return ((GenericValueType)(results[0]));
}
```

Is there any way of logging the response xml before is being deserialized by the framework? Any help or idea is very welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for doing this in a clean manner is to create a SOAP extension. I found a good tutorial here.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/efficientsoapextension.aspx